# DataLoader worker exited unexpectedly?

Tags: python, machine-learning, yolo

I am running this code seen on this Medium article: https://medium.com/@bentanweihao/training-a-custom-object-detector-in-half-a-day-with-yolov8-5e1475fe201e

Specifically the actual training portion:

```
from ultralytics import 
YOLO model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt") 
model.train(data="data.yaml", epochs=20) 
metrics = model.val()
```

And I receive back this error:

```
     25         def decorate_context(*args, **kwargs):
     26             with self.__class__():
...
--> 999                 raise RuntimeError('DataLoader worker (pid(s) {}) exited unexpectedly'.format(pids_str)) from e
   1000             if isinstance(e, queue.Empty):
   1001                 return (False, None)

RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid(s) 21812, 23384, 6272, 20544, 27792, 27784, 17928, 15588, 28072, 24112) exited unexpectedly
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me was this:

```
model.train(data="data.yaml", epochs=20,workers=0)
```

this is due to windows thread.

Comment: Hello, please explain "this is due to Windows thread". That's not nearly detailed enough.